# Why is div tag considering the wrong div tag as its ending tag?

Tags: html, css

Here the div tag with class="outlay" is considering the closing of div tag with id="4" as its closing tag. Why is this mismatch occurring?

```
<div class="outlay">
        <div class="screen"></div>
        <div class="grid-outlay">
            <div class="num" id="1">1</div>
            <div class="num" id="2">2</div>
            <div class="num" id="3">3</div>
            <div class="num" id="4">4</div>
            <div class="num" id="5">5</div>
            <div class="num" id="6">6</div>
            <div class="num" id="7">7</div>
            <div class="num" id="8">8</div>
            <div class="num" id="9">9</div>
            <div class="num" id="0">0</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to check all of your document HTML not only this part. may be the problem is with the former sections

Comment: An addition to @SaeedJamali's answer, this might also be caused by your IDE.

Comment: thanks it was the problem with my IDE(VS2)

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine for me, you could try inspecting it in the browser to find the reason

Comment: It was due to the IDE(VisualStudioCode2) but then i ran it with sublime...... then it went well